# Generate $x$ values using start and end points using Slope equation/formula

Tags: slope

I know the start and the end points of a slope.How do I get all the $(x,y)$ values between the start and end point.
For example: When $x = 0$, $y = 5$ and $x = 20000$, $y = 20$.
How do I generate the $y$ values when $x$ ranges from $0$ to $20000$?

Comment: Are u thinking about a machinery approach?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Slope formula:

$$m=\frac{y_2-y_1}{x_2-x_1}=\frac{20-5}{20000-0}=\frac3{4000}$$

Point-slope formula:

$$y-y_2=m(x-x_2)$$

$$y-5=\frac3{4000}(x-0)=\frac3{4000}x$$

$$y=\frac3{4000}x+5$$

Answer (score 2):

The points satisfy an equation $y=ax+b$, the equation of a (non-vertical) line. You need to find out the values of $a$ and $b$. If you plug in the points you already have, you get the system

$$\left\{\begin{array}{l}
5=a\cdot0+b\\
20=a\cdot20000+b
\end{array}\right.$$

Do you think you can take it from here?

Comment: Yes. I was using y=mx + c.Just didn't know I could simply plug in the values and find m.Thanks